# How to query for a substring within a sql string

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have log sql string and I'd like to query for a substring of it. The string is of a similar form to this:

```
2014-04-16 00:01:31-0400,583 {"Items":[{"EventName":"REDISTRIBUTION","PubEndDate":"2014/04/04","HistoryId":30330244,"AlertId":311116,"ItmId":"1515998685","SourceType":"Trade Journals","ReasonCode":"","Origin":"Alert","MyResearchUser":"610165","ProjectCode":"","PublicationCode":"0FQN","PubStartDate":"2014/04/04","ItmFrmt":"ResultItem","Subrole":"ResultItem","PaymentType":"PrePaid","NumberOfCopies":1,"UsageInfo":"P-1008254-158123-CUSTOMER-null-3667449","Role":"ResultItem","RetailPrice":0.39,"EffectivePrice":0,"Multiplier":1,"ParentItemId":"186168"},{"EventName":"REDISTRIBUTION","PubEndDate":"2014/06/30","HistoryId":30330244,"AlertId":311116,"ItmId":"1515993519","SourceType":"Trade Journals","ReasonCode":"","Origin":"Alert","MyResearchUser":"610165","ProjectCode":"","PublicationCode":"3GGY","PubStartDate":"2014/04/01","ItmFrmt":"ResultItem","Subrole":"ResultItem","PaymentType":"PrePaid","NumberOfCopies":1,"UsageInfo":"P-1008254-158123-CUSTOMER-null-3667449","Role":"ResultItem","RetailPrice":0.39,"EffectivePrice":0,"Multiplier":1,"ParentItemId":"186168"},{"EventName":"REDISTRIBUTION","PubEndDate":"2014/06/30","HistoryId":30330244,"AlertId":311116,"ItmId":"1515993511","SourceType":"Trade Journals","ReasonCode":"","Origin":"Alert","MyResearchUser":"610165","ProjectCode":"","PublicationCode":"3GGY","PubStartDate":"2014/04/01","ItmFrmt":"ResultItem","Subrole":"ResultItem","PaymentType":"PrePaid","NumberOfCopies":1,"UsageInfo":"P-1008254-158123-CUSTOMER-null-3667449","Role":"ResultItem","RetailPrice":0.39,"EffectivePrice":0,"Multiplier":1,"ParentItemId":"186168"},{"EventName":"REDISTRIBUTION","PubEndDate":"2014/03/31","HistoryId":30330244,"AlertId":311116,"ItmId":"1516002290","SourceType":"Trade Journals","ReasonCode":"","Origin":"Alert","MyResearchUser":"610165","ProjectCode":"","PublicationCode":"0EUH","PubStartDate":"2014/03/31","ItmFrmt":"ResultItem","Subrole":"ResultItem","PaymentType":"PrePaid","NumberOfCopies":1,"UsageInfo":"P-1008254-158123-CUSTOMER-null-3667449","Role":"ResultItem","RetailPrice":0.39,"EffectivePrice":0,"Multiplier":1,"ParentItemId":"186168"},{"EventName":"REDISTRIBUTION","PubEndDate":"2014/02/28","HistoryId":30330244,"AlertId":311116,"ItmId":"1515999310","SourceType":"Trade Journals","ReasonCode":"","Origin":"Alert","MyResearchUser":"610165","ProjectCode":"","PublicationCode":"1ZEC","PubStartDate":"2014/02/01","ItmFrmt":"ResultItem","Subrole":"ResultItem","PaymentType":"PrePaid","NumberOfCopies":1,"UsageInfo":"P-1008254-158123-CUSTOMER-null-3667449","Role":"ResultItem","RetailPrice":0.39,"EffectivePrice":0,"Multiplier":1,"ParentItemId":"186168"},{"EventName":"REDISTRIBUTION","PubEndDate":"2014/01/31","HistoryId":30330244,"AlertId":311116,"ItmId":"1515993424","SourceType":"Trade Journals","ReasonCode":"","Origin":"Alert","MyResearchUser":"610165","ProjectCode":"","PublicationCode":"5AMP","PubStartDate":"2014/01/01","ItmFrmt":"ResultItem","Subrole":"ResultItem","PaymentType":"PrePaid","NumberOfCopies":1,"UsageInfo":"P-1008254-158123-CUSTOMER-null-3667449","Role":"ResultItem","RetailPrice":0.39,"EffectivePrice":0,"Multiplier":1,"ParentItemId":"186168"},{"EventName":"REDISTRIBUTION","PubEndDate":"2014/01/31","HistoryId":30330244,"AlertId":311116,"ItmId":"1515993462","SourceType":"Trade Journals","ReasonCode":"","Origin":"Alert","MyResearchUser":"610165","ProjectCode":"","PublicationCode":"5AMP","PubStartDate":"2014/01/01","ItmFrmt":"ResultItem","Subrole":"ResultItem","PaymentType":"PrePaid","NumberOfCopies":1,"UsageInfo":"P-1008254-158123-CUSTOMER-null-3667449","Role":"ResultItem","RetailPrice":0.39,"EffectivePrice":0,"Multiplier":1,"ParentItemId":"186168"},{"EventName":"REDISTRIBUTION","PubEndDate":"2014/01/31","HistoryId":30330244,"AlertId":311116,"ItmId":"1515993356","SourceType":"Trade Journals","ReasonCode":"","Origin":"Alert","MyResearchUser":"610165","ProjectCode":"","PublicationCode":"5AMP","PubStartDate":"2014/01/01","ItmFrmt":"ResultItem","Subrole":"ResultItem","PaymentType":"PrePaid","NumberOfCopies":1,"UsageInfo":"P-1008254-158123-CUSTOMER-null-3667449","Role":"ResultItem","RetailPrice":0.39,"EffectivePrice":0,"Multiplier":1,"ParentItemId":"186168"},{"EventName":"REDISTRIBUTION","PubEndDate":"2014/01/31","HistoryId":30330244,"AlertId":311116,"ItmId":"1515993516","SourceType":"Trade Journals","ReasonCode":"","Origin":"Alert","MyResearchUser":"610165","ProjectCode":"","PublicationCode":"5AMP","PubStartDate":"2014/01/01","ItmFrmt":"ResultItem","Subrole":"ResultItem","PaymentType":"PrePaid","NumberOfCopies":1,"UsageInfo":"P-1008254-158123-CUSTOMER-null-3667449","Role":"ResultItem","RetailPrice":0.39,"EffectivePrice":0,"Multiplier":1,"ParentItemId":"186168"}],"Operation":["optype:Email","location:null","target:null"],"UserInfo":{"IP":"172.27.242.164","AppId":"DIALOG","SessId":"20140416040131549:367642","UsageGroupId":"1138209"},"UsageType":"multiRetrieve","BreadCrumb":"OS-AlertEmailBase-logAlertEmail-2-AlertID-311116"}
```

I'd like to query for the item in quotes after the ItmFrmt key, in this case the value "ResultItem" but in the full database various values will be between those quotes.

Comment: Have you looked at the [native `JSON` support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) in `PostgreSQL`?

Comment: Would this work, given the entire string is not JSON?

Comment: Is **everything** from (and including) initial `{` in a `JSON` format?

Comment: Then you may want to consider this route.  You other option is [`REGEX`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table_name
WHERE jsonFieldName like '%"ItmFrmt":"ResultItem"%'
```

This will give you all fields that have that exact part of the String.

Comment: I only want to get the "ResultItem" part - without the rest. Like to count how many of them say "ResultItem" vs how many say "Text"

Comment: To get the count you can get COUNT... ?

Comment: But this would only count the ones called "ResultItem", it doesn't group by the generic value

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex_replace](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) to get the text you want.

```
 select regexp_replace(columnName, '.*"ItmFrmt":"(.*)",.*', '\1') as queryString
 from tableName
 where queryString ~ '"ItmFrmt":'
 and queryString ...
```

The first where clause will get you only entries that actually have the `ItemFrmt` piece, because the replace won't replace anything in non-matching lines and just report as-is.

`...` is to fill in what you're querying for. But beware that this doesn't handle special quoting of JSON. It may be better to put the JSON in a separate column/table and use the built-in JSON handling. Also, I can't vouch for how efficient this is, especially if you have a very large table.

Comment: You can COUNT() here, too. But if you want the actual value, this will give you it.